# Audio stops when using Audacity on Ubuntu Studio 18.10

Tags: sound, alsa, ubuntu-studio, audacity, audio-player

After I open Audacity, no sound will be played.

Closing Audacity doesn't fix it. Once I have ran it, my pc won't emit a single sound until I restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open [Ubuntu Studio Controls](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioControls) and click "Stop Jack" to make sure Jack is stopped (Audacity doesn't use it). That should make your audio settings the default.

Otherwise, try the following troubleshooting steps:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sound
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting
- https://alsa.opensrc.org/DmixPlugin